# "Maximum upload size" does not correspond to php.ini settings

Tags: php, lampp, max-size

I'm using lampp on ubuntu and I want to change the maximum upload size.

The php.ini in opt/lampp/etc has these settings:

```
post_max_size = 5M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
```

But when I try to upload a 2.1 mo file, I have this error message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7448 bytes)
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Have you restarted apache yet?

Comment: Check the php.ini path and max_filesize settings by doing a <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: i did reboot my computer

Comment: @iTom it is the right php.ini, also I didn't find any max_filesize settings in phpinfo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not because the post_max_size or upload_max_filesize, but because of memory limit
try this

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
```

134217728 bytes = 128MB

or from php.ini

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

But in general, when you got this error, it simply means that your code is not efficient yet. Because you are exhausting the allocated memory to run just this one PHP page. It's already 128 MB you know.
If you simply just increase the memory limit, the concurrent PHP processes that can be opened at the same time would be reduced significantly.
Try to think of massive multi-user environment, when this PHP page is opened by many users at the same time, can the server handle it all with the server's physical memory ?

Simply put, can you share your piece of code here so we all can help you to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted **Apache**?

Have you tried the **PHP** method?

Have you tried the **htaccess** method?

### PHP method

```
ini_set('upload_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
```

### Htaccess method

try putting this in your .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is not related to the file upload size.  PHP is running out of memory (RAM) during the execution of your script.

You will need to increase your memory limit per the PHP ini settings: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to the max upload file size, it's related to the PHP interpreter trying to allocate more memory than allowed by the `memory_limit` flag.

Increase it's value in PHP.INI, reatart your server, check if the new value is in use with `phpinfo()` and see if your script works.